# how to use Manipulate changing the values of a List?

Tags: list-manipulation, manipulate

How can I "change" the values in the list h={2,4,6} using Manipulate?

(Next line was edited after hte first Alexi´s comment)
I WANT to choose real values in h[[1]], h[[3]] , h[[3]]  between 0 and 8.

I was trying, typing at the final line

{h[[1]],1,8},{h[[2]],1,8},{h[[3]],1,8},{zmax, Range[8]}

instead

```
{zmax, Range[8]}
```

But I obtain this error:
Manipulate::vsform: "Manipulate argument {h[[1]],1,8} does not have the correct form for a variable specification"

---

```
Manipulate[

 h = {2, 4, 6};

 Column[{
   Row[{

     TableForm[Table[h^z, {z, 1, zmax}], 
      TableHeadings -> {None, {"Number", "Square", "Cube"}}]
     }
    ],

   Row[{
     PieChart[Table[i^2, {i, 1, zmax}], ChartLabels -> Range[zmax], 
      ImageSize -> 200],

     PieChart[Table[i^3, {i, 1, zmax}], ChartLabels -> Range[zmax], 
      ImageSize -> 200],

     PieChart[Range[zmax], ChartLabels -> Range[zmax], 
      ImageSize -> 200]
     }
    ]
   }]
 , {zmax, Range[8]}]
```

Comment: This strongly depends upon What do you want to achieve? This is not clear from your post.

Comment: \alexei-boulbitch  I WANT to choose real values in h[[1]], h[[3]] , h[[3]]  between 0 and 8.  This is a little to ilustrate me for a major progrma that I´m doing for a personal math program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    Manipulate[
 h = {h1, h2, h3};
 Column[{Row[{TableForm[Table[h^z, {z, 1, zmax}], 
      TableHeadings -> {None, {"Number", "Square", "Cube"}}]}], 
   Row[{PieChart[Table[i^2, {i, 1, zmax}], ChartLabels -> Range[zmax],
       ImageSize -> 200], 
     PieChart[Table[i^3, {i, 1, zmax}], ChartLabels -> Range[zmax], 
      ImageSize -> 200], 
     PieChart[Range[zmax], ChartLabels -> Range[zmax], 
      ImageSize -> 200]}]}], {zmax, Range[8]}, {h1, 0, 8}, {h2, 0, 
  8}, {h3, 0, 8}]
```